# Why is JS/JQuery function inside JSTL is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

In my JSP, I calling a JSP function based on the value of JSTL. I see the alert statement inside the JS (inside JSTL) working , but not the JQuery. Why is that?

```
<c:set var = "error" value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>
<c:choose>                  

    <c:when test="${error=='not unregistered'}"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
               alert("Hi"); 
               openSignUp();
            </script>                                                                               
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />                                             
    </c:otherwise>                                      
</c:choose>                     
<c:remove var = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION" scope = "session" />   

<script>
   function openSignUp(){
         $('#signUp_dialog').dialog({
            width:350,
            open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-button-text").remove();
            $(".ui-dialog-title").css("margin-right","275px");
            }
         });                    
    }

</script>
```

I tried following as well, by putting directly the code inside JS function inside the script tags of JSTL. Still no luck.

```
<c:set var = "error" value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>
<c:choose>                  
    <c:when test="${error=='not unregistered'}"> 
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="<c:url value="/resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js" />">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#signUp_dialog').dialog({

                width:350,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    alert("hi");
                    $(".ui-button-text").remove();
                $(".ui-dialog-title").css("margin-right","275px");
                }
             });    
        });     
        </script>                                                                               
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />                                             
    </c:otherwise>                                      
</c:choose>                     
<c:remove var = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION" scope = "session" />
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If the "signUp_dialog" element appears *after* that point in the DOM, then it won't work because your code won't find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code (whether it's plain java script or jquery) should fire on page load (after all the java/jsp/jstl processing has been finished). So , call openSignUp in a script block at the end of your JSP page (after all the elements have been processed).

```
...JSP page
<script>
//openSignUp definition here

//check the condition first
if(${error} == 'not unregistered'})//this should translate to either true or false
{
  openSignUp();//if the conditon is true, call the dialog
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported jquery related files?
Also check view source after loading page.

Comment: This should be a comment not answer.